# Locking a process to Cuda core

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I'm just getting into GPU processing.

I was wondering if it's possible to lock a new process, or 'launch' a process that is **locked** to a CUDA core?

For example you may have a small C program that performs an image filter on an index of images. Can you have that program running on each CUDA core that essentially runs forever - reading/writing from it's own memory to system memory and disk?

If this is possible, what are the implications for CPU performance - can we totally offset CPU usage or does the CPU still need to have some input/output?

My semantics here are probably way off. I apologize if what i've said requries some interpretation. I'm not that used to GPU stuff yet.

Thanks.

Comment: As of this comment, CUDA threads are not guaranteed to run concurrently with any threads other than those within their own thread block. This includes CPU threads you may wish to attempt communication with in your hypothetical example. You might be able to get something that happened to work, but the behavior wouldn't be supported. That is, your program would likely break if the system decided to change the schedule of threads in your program. Moreover, CUDA threads cannot make system calls in general, such as those required to access a disk.

Comment: Can CUDA threads send packets over a network?

Comment: Not sure; in general, probably not. You may wish to read about CUDA's "GPUDirect" features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of my comments here should be prefaced with "at the moment".  Technology is constantly evolving.

> was wondering if it's possible to lock a new process, or 'launch' a process that is locked to a CUDA core?

*process* is mostly a (host) operating system term.  CUDA doesn't define a *process* separately from the host operating system definition of it, AFAIK.  CUDA *threadblocks*, once launched on a [Streaming Multiprocessor](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#hardware-implementation) (or *SM*, a hardware execution resource component inside a GPU), in many cases will stay on that SM for their "lifetime", and the SM includes an array of "CUDA cores" (a bit of a loose or conceptual term).  However, there is at least [one documented exception](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#sm-id-and-warp-id) today to this in the case of CUDA Dynamic Parallelism, so in the most general sense, it is not possible to "lock" a CUDA thread of execution to a CUDA core (using core here to refer to that thread of execution forever remaining on a given warp lane within a SM).

> Can you have that program running on each CUDA core that essentially runs forever

You can have a CUDA program that runs essentially forever.  It is a recognized programming technique sometimes referred to as [persistent threads](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2012/presentations/S0157-Persistent-Threads-Style-Programming-Model-for-GPU-Computing.pdf).  Such a program will naturally occupy/require one or more CUDA cores (again, using the term loosely).  As already stated, that may or may not imply that the program permanently occupies a *particular* set of physical execution resources.

> reading/writing from it's own memory to system memory

Yes, that's possible, extending the train of thought.  Writing to it's own memory is obviously possible, by definition, and writing to system memory is possible via the [zero-copy mechanism](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_Webinars_CUDA_Memory_Optimization.pdf) (slides 21/22), given a reasonable assumption of appropriate setup activity for this mechanism.

> and disk?

No, that's not directly possible today, without host system interaction, and/or without a significant assumption of atypical external resources such as a disk controller of some sort connected via a GPUDirect interface (with a lot of additional assumptions and unspecified framework).  The GPUDirect exception requires so much additional framework, that I would say, for typical usage, the answer is "no", not without host system activity/intervention.  The host system (normally) owns the disk drive, not the GPU.

> If this is possible, what are the implications for CPU performance - can we totally offset CPU usage or does the CPU still need to have some input/output?

In my opinion, the CPU must still be considered.  One consideration is if you need to write to disk.  Even if you don't, most programs derive I/O from somewhere (e.g. MPI) and so the implication of a larger framework of some sort is there.  Secondly, and relatedly, the persistent threads programming model usually implies a producer/consumer relationship, and a work queue.  The GPU is on the processing side (consumer side) of the work queue, but something else (usually) is on the producer side, typically the host system CPU.  Again, it could be another GPU, either locally or via MPI, that is on the producer side of the work queue, but that still usually implies an ultimate producer somewhere else (i.e. the need for system I/O).

Additionally:

> Can CUDA threads send packets over a network?

This is like the disk question.  These questions could be viewed in a general way, in which case the answer might be "yes".  But restricting ourselves to formal definitions of what a CUDA thread can do, I believe the answer is more reasonably "no".  CUDA provides no direct definitions for I/O interfaces to disk or network (or many other things, such as a display!).  It's reasonable to conjecture or presume the existence of a lightweight host process that simply copies packets between a CUDA GPU and a network interface.  With this presumption, the answer might be "yes" (and similarly for disk I/O).  But without this presumption (and/or a related, perhaps more involved presumption of a GPUDirect framework), I think the most reasonable answer is "no".  According to the CUDA programming model, there is no definition of how to access a disk or network resource directly.

Comment: I think a network port on high-end Nvidia cards would be amazing :) Perhaps they can do a separate network card and connect in series with SLI? Thanks for your answer. You are most definitely covering everything with great references. Green tick.